# How to un-highlight tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift2, uitableview

I'm using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
aCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? UITableViewCell
```

where aCell is a class level variable.

This works fine but I noticed clicked cells remain gray. Is there a way to un-highlight them when another cell is clicked?

I can store the previously clicked NSIndexPath but I'm not sure how to access any type of cell un-highlight method or property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. How to Get a Reference to a Visible Cell

It's not entirely clear from your question but it looks like you're using `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:forIndexPath:)` inside `tableView(_:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:)`.

You shouldn't do that.

`dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:forIndexPath:)` is intended to be used inside `tableView(_:cellForRowAtIndexPath:)` where you configure your cells. It either creates and initializes a **new** cell or returns a **cell for reuse** that was scrolled off screen. The point is: It will never return a pointer to cell that's currently visible.

If you want to get a reference to a currently visible cell use `cellForRowAtIndexPath(_:)` instead on the table view.

---

### 2. Properly Deselecting a Cell

If you only want to **deselect a cell at a certain index path**
you don't even need to get a reference to the actual cell. You can simply achieve the desired behavior by passing the `indexPath` of the row to the table view's *deselect* method. For example, if you want to animatedly deselect a cell right after the user has tapped on it, you can do it like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

---

### 3. More Information

For further information please refer to the [Table View Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) and the documentation of the method `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:forIndexPath:)` in the [UITableView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:).

Comment: How does #2 deselect a cell? That's the current cell.

Comment: It deselects the cell that was just selected by the user using an animation. So it'll turn grey when the user taps that row and fades back to white when the user releases his finger. I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. If you want to deselect another cell at any time just call `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)` for the appropriate index path.

Comment: If it's still not what you want please refine your question and maybe add the whole relevant code inside your `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` function.

Comment: Tried deselectRowAtIndexPath but still no effect. There's nothing more for me to post. Like I said in the OP, clicked cells remain gray. Eventually, the entire table of rows is gray.

Comment: Have you checked your table view's background color? May be that's where the gray color comes from? It's the only other explanation that comes to my mind. Because `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)` is really the way to go. I've done that many times and just checked again in a sample project and it works just fine.

Comment: It would really help if you could post your whole implementation of the `tableView(_:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:)` delegate function or the code inside the scope where you try to deselect the cell. I'm afraid that without that information I won't be able to help you.

Comment: Found the problem. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath, I have a rogue call to tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. Replacing that with cellForRowAtIndexPath eliminates the need for any of the color change or selected state updates.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to remove the selected state of a cell you will need to call set the selected state to false
In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Is this function working??")
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) //get the correct cell     

    cell?.selected = false //Will no longer be selected. Gray tableviewcell will now be normal.
}
```

Comment: I have just done the same thing at it works. See my updated code

Answer (score 0):

Change the selected view property of cell to view with clear color. If you need the code let me know

1. change selection style (Swift 2) you can do the same on storyboard.

   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
2. create custom view

   let selectedView = UIView()

   selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

   cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView

Comment: yes - please show the code. I tried changing selected to false but no effect.

Comment: @4thSpace change cell selection style  to none. Try doing that.

Comment: Tried UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None and UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.Default. Still no effect.